# How can I sort material table based on nested component

Tags: angular, angular-material

app-message-action component renders translated row.action based on the selected language. How do I sort the table by this translated string? It currently sorts well by row.action but value of raw.action is different from the string rendered by nested component.

```
   <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header i18n>Action</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" width="60%">
          <app-message-action [deviceTypeId]="deviceTypeId" [key]="'action'" [action]="row.action"></app-message-action>
        </td>
   </ng-container>
```

I tried:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="action" matSortDirection="asc">
```

even considered to overwrite sortingDataAccessor but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

this is my sort for nested objects.

for example I sort requestOwner by their lastnames. So in case 'requestOwner' I return item.requestOwner.lastName. It works similar for other fields.

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'status': return item.statusId;
        case 'requestOwner': return item.requestOwner.lastName;
        case 'vehicles': return item.requestVehicles[0].vehicle.plateNumber;
        case 'driver': return item.requestVehicles[0].driver.lastName;
        case 'startDate': return item.requestVehicles[0].startDateTime;
        case 'endDate': return item.requestVehicles[0].endDateTime;
        case 'locations': return item.requestVehicles[0].routes[0].regionName;
        default: return item[property];
      }
    };
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

this is how my data looks like:

```
{
"requestId": 0,
"requestOwner": {
    "departmentId": 0,
    "email": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "personId": 0,
    "phoneNumber": "string",
    "userName": "string"
},
"requestVehicles": [
    {
        "driver": {
            "departmentId": 0,
            "email": "string",
            "firstName": "string",
            "lastName": "string",
            "personId": 0,
            "phoneNumber": "string",
            "userName": "string"
        },
        "endDateTime": "2019-03-25T09:29:42.097Z",
        "routes": [
            {
                "addressPointId": "string",
                "id": 0,
                "municipalityId": 0,
                "regionId": 0,
                "rvId": 0,
                "sequenceNumber": 0,
                "settlementId": 0
            }
        ],
        "vehicle": {
            "additionalInfo": "string",
            "currentDriver": {
                "departmentId": 0,
                "email": "string",
                "firstName": "string",
                "lastName": "string",
                "personId": 0,
                "phoneNumber": "string",
                "userName": "string"
            },
            "startDateTime": "2019-03-25T09:29:42.097Z",
        }
    ],
    "statusId": 0
}
```

also these are my display columns:

```
  displayedColumns = ['status', 'requestOwner', 'vehicles', 'driver', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'locations', 'additionalInfo', 'priority'];
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution applies to nested object but I do not have an issue with nested object but nested component. Component app-message-action has 3 inputs: device type, message key and message action and renders translated action based on some JSON config... I do not see a way how to use your solution.

Comment: my bad. misunderstood the question.

Comment: I end up by getting rid of the inner component and translated the actions by service but I still think there must be a solution for this...

Comment: maybe you could use shared service to transfer your data. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ the fourth method here.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did but I was curious if there is a method with embedded component...